# Open Notebook Minimized to TaskBar

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I want to open a temporary notebook without displaying its contents, and have it running minimized, in the TaskBar.  Its purpose is simply to run a setup script, after which it is closed.  Hence I want to hide it from the user.

The best I have been able to achieve so far is with:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize-> {1,1}]
```

which keeps it very small, but it's still visible on the desktop.

Setting Visible-> False renders the notebook completely invisible, and its cant be seen, even in the TaskBar.  Thats not what is required.

Likewise, setting WindowOpacity->0 is a kind of work-around, but again its not really what I want.

Comment: Try setting the visible option to false.

Comment: Is that the same thing?  I tried that and the notebook wasn't visible, even in the taskbar.

Comment: Could [SessionSubmit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SessionSubmit.html) be an alternative way running that code?